# Filter Array List using concatenated string angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, angular-pipe

I am trying to filter an array of string using filter

```
var employeeRole=['Manager', 'Employee', 'Director', 'Supervisor', 'TeamLead'];
var permittedRoles='Manager|Director';
```

How could I find if either of `permittedRoles` contains in `employeeRole`

Comment: Why do you put angular tags while you're only asking for javascript help? You need to learn how to manipulate strings and arrays in js before learning a framework like angular.

Comment: I don't want to manipulate strings. My Web Service is returning this string ('Manager|Director')
I have to apply condition accordingly.
I want to perform an operation with help of filters or pipe operator.

Comment: @SwapnilBapat I don't quite understand your question. You want to know if any of the values separated by `|` in `permittedRoles` is within `employeeRole` ...? or vice versa: any of the values in `employeeRole` is in the string `permittedRoles`?

Comment: @lealceldeiro
"You want to know if any of the values separated by | in permittedRoles is within employeeRole" Yes!

Comment: @SwapnilBapat, check this [answer I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676697/filter-array-list-using-concatenated-string-angular-js/49693700#49693700) and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by [splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `permittedRoles` by `|` and checking if any of the values (use of [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)) in the resultant array is contained (use of [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)) in `employeeRole`.

See below a full example:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.employeeRole = ['Manager', 'Employee', 'Director', 'Supervisor', 'TeamLead'];
    $scope.permittedRoles = 'Manager|Director';

    $scope.check = function() {
      console.log(doCheck())
    };

    /**
     * Return `true` if any of the values in `permittedRoles` separated by `|` is contained in the array `employeeRole`, `false` otherwise.
     */
    function doCheck() {
      return $scope.permittedRoles.split('|')
        .some(
          function(role) {
            return $scope.employeeRole.indexOf(role) !== -1;
          }
        );
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <label for="permittedRoles">permittedRoles: </label>
  <input id="permittedRoles" ng-model="permittedRoles" />

  <hr/>
  <a href="#" ng-click="check()">Check (click me!)</a>
  <hr/>
  <label>employeeRole:</label>
  <br/>
  <div ng-repeat="role in employeeRole">
    {{role}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, @SwapnilBapat! Please, remember  [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it solved your problem. Happy codding!